# Why are query strings ignored depending on my router order?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, api, express

As a lot of people here, I'm trying to learn programming by myself. I have just started learning Express and API building and I can't seem to find why the following happens when setting my routes. For example, if I have:

```
import express from "express"

import cors from 'cors'

import { users, posts } from "./variables"

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.use(cors())

app.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3003");
});

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {          
    res.send(posts)
})

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {          
    let userId = Number(req.query.userId)
    let arrayPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.userId === userId)
    res.send(arrayPosts)
})
```

Where my variables are:

```
import { User, Post } from "./types"

export let users : User[] = [
    {id : 1, name: "Test 1"},
    {id : 2, name: "Test 2"},
]


export let posts : Post[] = [
    {id : 1, title : "Bla bla", body : "Bla bla bla bla", userId: 1},
    {id : 2, title : "Ble ble", body : "Ble ble ble ble", userId: 2},
]
```

And I hit the endpoint http://localhost:3003/posts?userId=1, I get all posts. However, as soon as I change orders:

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {          
    let userId = Number(req.query.userId)
    let arrayPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.userId === userId)
    res.send(arrayPosts)
})

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {          
    res.send(posts)
})
```

It works as expected. Is that how is it supposed to be? If positive, why? It doesn't seem intuitive tbh.

Edit:

So the first two comments made me realize I should just

```
    app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {          
        let userId = req.query.userId ? Number(req.query.userId) : 0
        if (userId) {
            let arrayPosts = posts.filter((post) => post.userId === userId)
            res.send(arrayPosts)
        } else {
            res.send(posts)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Why do you think that's two different routes?

Comment: If you have two routes that are exactly the same, Express will only pick one of them. What is it that you *expected* to happen?

Comment: Now I feel kind of stupid tbh. LOL 

Your comments made me realize I should just check if the query string is present in my first route and then return the content accordingly.

Thanks.